# clj-http returns status 200 but cljs-http client returns status 0 for the same request

Tags: clojure, cors, clojurescript, clj-http

I make a request like so using clj-http.client

```
(http/get "https://www.example.com/bar")
```

and get a response with status 200.

However, when I make the same request with cljs-http.client like so:

```
(go (let [response (<! (http/get (str "https://example.com" "/bar")))]
         (prn response)))
```

I get a response with status 0, and in the browser it says that it's been blocked by the cors policy.

Why would the cljs-http.client request be blocked by the cors policy if the clj-http.client request isn't?

```
(defn response [data & [status]]
  {:status (or status 200)
   :headers {"Content-Type" "application/edn"
             "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type"
             "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
             "Access-Control-Request-Method" "GET"}
   :body (pr-str data)})
```

I wrap my response for route "bar" with the function response above.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the HTTP library used: If you are in a browser context, the browser has full control over the actual HTTP request and will enforce CORS.

If you call from a non-browser context, you have full control over the HTTP exchange.

Your only option is to make sure your server-side understands CORS and returns the correct HTTP headers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for a description of what the server-side needs to do.

If you are using ring, wrapping your routes with `wrap-cors` is one possibility.

To test your CORS routes from clj, make sure you send HTTP requests with an `Origin` header set.
Your ring route should respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to the allowed origins. (Often '*' is used, which is fine for simple request)